# Use of Data Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net

As per MSDN: "One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it remains valid as long as the application domain remains active. Information about an instance of this class is available through the Cache property of the `HttpContext` object or the `Cache` property of the `Page` object."

As per my knowledge, `HttpContext` and `Page` Object life is valid for single http request. So what is the use of Cache Property (Data caching) when I cant use it for another request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN is correct: `HttpContext.Cache` lives for your entire application lifecycle, not just over a request.

You are correct that the `HttpContext` lives per request, but the `Cache` object lives over the entire application life. The framework makes sure to assign the correct `Cache` instance whenever creating an `HttpContext` for you.

Comment: I marked it as an answer. Thanks. Got one more doubt, What you mean by 'application lifecycle'. Shall I take it like from HttpApplication object creation to destory. Or will life cycle will continue when the same HttpApplication object is reused for another page request from the same application?

Comment: The application lifecycle is the entire span of life for your application, it begins with Application_Start, and ends when your application pool is shut down or recycled. Even if multiple HttpApplication objects are in play, there will be only one Application_Start event.

Comment: So you mean, till application pool is shut down or recycled, I can use my cached objects across different requests correct?

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext` and `Page` might only be valid on a request basis. The cache however is on application level. Just because you can access the Cache object using  `HttpContext` and `Page` does not mean they have the same lifespan.